# How to use openvpn with tcpvpn?

Tags: networking, linux-kernel, kali-linux, openvpn, vpn

Is it possible to use openvpn with the configuration downloaded from [tcpvpn.com](http://tcpvpn.com) ?(.ovpn format) I have already created my account on tcpvpn settings are

```
Username : tcpvpn.com-linuxme
Password : *******
IP : 128.199.205.250
Host : sg-mct1.tcpvpn.com
```

Now, how do I import these settings to openvpn? I already installed it on my Kali Linux (with GUI)

[image]

Next is I want to add my own custom header in the configuration, with these, I am sure that my remote proxy is working, i checked it.

```
http-proxy-retry
http-proxy 128.x.x.x port#
http-proxy-option CUSTOM-HEADER Host: http://mypayload.com (my own payload)
http-proxy-option CUSTOM-HEADER Host: Keep-Alive
keepalive 10 30
auto-ping-server http://mypayload.com
dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8
dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4
dhcp-option DOMAIN http://client3.google.com/
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using network-manager then you should be able to import from the command line like [this](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-import-openvpn-ovpn-file-with-networkmanager-commandline/)

```
nmcli connection import type openvpn file /path/to/your/whateverItIsCalled.ovpn
```